# mapping data array with nested arrays

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

using Next.JS react with TSX file have a data file set up as so

```
const fieldMapping = {
category:[
   {
  
    title: "Category 1",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2"],
    SubSubTitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ]
  
  },
  {

    title: "Category 2",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ],
    SubSubTitle: [
      {title: "Category 1", link : "/"},
      {title: "Category 2", link : "/"}, 
      {title: "Category 3", link : "/"}, 
      {title: "Category 4", link : "/"}, 
      {title: "Category 5", link : "/"}, 
      {title: "Category 6", link : "/"}, 
  ]
    
  },
  {
    title: "Category 3",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2"],
    SubSubTitle: [
    {title: "Category 1", link : "/"},
    {title: "Category 2", link : "/"}, 
    {title: "Category 3", link : "/"}, 
    {title: "Category 4", link : "/"}, 
    {title: "Category 5", link : "/"}, 
    {title: "Category 6", link : "/"}, ]
    
  },
  {
    title: "Category 4",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ],
    SubSubTitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ]
  },
  {
    title: "Category 5",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ],
    SubSubTitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ]
    
  },
  {
    title: "Category 6",
    Subtitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ],
    SubSubTitle: ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5" ]
    
  },

]
}
export default fieldMapping
```

and the render item as such

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import fieldMapping from "./data-mapping";


export default function NavItems(

) {
const renderLists= () =>{
 
    let item = fieldMapping.category;
    return (
        <div>
       <p>{item[0].title}</p>
       <p>{item[0].Subtitle}</p>
       <p>{item[0].SubSubTitle}</p>
    </div>
    )
    };
return (
    {renderLists}
)

}
```

error is this ::: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {renderLists}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

i am attempting to map the data to a function when click category 1 items will show. then if clicked category 2 items would show this is a navigation menu so the sub categories will have sub categories as well. I haven't even tried a click action since i keep getting errorws with mapping

we can just list out the hard coded links but it's a lot was wanting to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You cant show an array in a tag.

```
{item[0].Subtitle.map(sub => <p>sub</p>)
{item[0].SubSubTitle.map(subSub => <p>subSub</p>)
```

Comment: thanks, still getting the error though :/ trying to see if the data structure is wrong now

Comment: sorry it should be 

```
{item[0].SubSubTitle.map(subSub => <p>{subSub.title}</p>)
````

Comment: also  ``` return (
    {renderLists()}
).  ```

Comment: ive got it somewhat working now with this 

  const renderLists = () => {
        let item = fieldMapping
        if (toggle1 ){
            return (
                
            <Card>
               <Col>
                 { item.category.map((x) => { return <div key={x}>{x.title}</div>})}
                <ul >
                    { item.category.Subtitle.map((index) => { return <li key={index}>{index.SubSubTitle.title}</li>})}
                    </ul>  
               </Col> 
               </Card>
            )
        }

Comment: i'll keep trying lol but it's getting there